# Centos grub bootloader missing after installing windows 10

Tags: windows, grub2, boot-loader

I first installed CentOS 7 on my laptop, 2nd I installed Windows 10 in same hard disk with different partition, but I couldn't get my Centos 7 info in windows boot loader. I tried easyBCD tool to get Centos 7 info in windows bootloader but failed to boot.

Answer (score 1):

I thought you should install Windows first, then CentOS. You didn't give info about what your system uses - BIOS or UEFI.

See [How can I dual-boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu on a UEFI HP notebook?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/666631/how-can-i-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-on-a-uefi-hp-notebook)

Comment: As you told, i did previously like installing centos 7 after windows 10. in this  case i can boot windows 10 by editing grub file in linux.

Comment: what is my question is, Is it possible possible to install windows after linux? and boot linux from windows bootloader?

Comment: You still haven't told us if you use UEFI or BIOS.

Comment: I have used BIOS only.

Comment: See "Editing the CentOS Boot Menu": http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Installing_CentOS_with_Windows_in_Dual_Boot_Environment

Comment: yes, finally I have got centos bootloader with help of centos 7 live Boot DVD by reinstalling the grub in my hard disk. After adding the Windows os information in "/boot/grub2/grub.cfg", i can get windows os option in centos 7 bootloader.

Comment: If your question is solved, you can accept this answer, and choose to upvote useful comments.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common thing, as SPRBRN mentioned you would normally install Windows first, as they are on separate drives can you boot from the drive that has CentOS installed?

If you can then you could update GRUB to include an entry for Windows and use this to then launch the windows boot loader, thus giving the ability to boot from both again :-)